# Hibernate ManyToMany mapping infinite DB calls

Tags: java, hibernate

Award Entity

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="awards", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Winner> winners = new HashSet<>();
```

Winner Entity

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="AWARD_ASSIGNMENT", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="WINNER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="AWARD_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private Set<Award> awards = new HashSet<>();
```

I am calling this hibernate fetch method

```
return getSession().createQuery("from Winner").list();
```

Hashcode equals method overriding in Awards entity

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((winners == null) ? 0 : winners.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Award other = (Award) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (winners == null) {
            if (other.winners != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!winners.equals(other.winners))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Winner entity

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((awards == null) ? 0 : awards.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Winner other = (Winner) obj;
        if (awards == null) {
            if (other.awards != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!awards.equals(other.awards))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Overriding equals and hashcode methods as Many to Many relation is using SET.

Comment: Do Award and Winner have equals / hashCode methods? if so please add the impl

Comment: I have added hashcode and equals method but still I see infinite calls

Comment: i mean.. add them to your post for us to see

Comment: @MaciejKowalski , I have posted the hashcode and equals methods I have  in my entities. Any issues here

Comment: If I empty the join table AWARD_ASSIGNMENT , don't see this issue

Answer (score 0):

Points to remember :

1) Make sure there are not Associations(One to many/ Many to many ..etc) in your hashcode or equal methods. while overriding hashcode / equals method use fields which make that object unique (ex.. FirstName + LastName + Phone number) try to avoid using PK Id generated by JPA .

2) Restrict Jackson/Json serialisation to avoid deep traversal .

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Award> awards = new HashSet<>();

@JsonBackReference
private Set<Winner> winners = new HashSet<>();
```